# Django how to call __init__ in abstract model?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oop, dry

I have a abstract model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class BaseModel(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletableModel):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='%(class)s_wallet',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    first_field = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    second_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._set_default_value()

    ...
    def _set_default_values(self):
        first_field = self.__class__._meta.get_field('first_field')
        second_field = self.__class__._meta.get_field('second_name')

        if self.__class__.__name__.lower().startswith('some'):
            first_field.default = 'some value'
            second_field.default = 'some value
    ...
```

and several models that are inherited from it

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    pass
```

But when I try to `makemigrations`, I get a message stating that `No changes detected`.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the *inor* method not called?

Comment: `self._set_default_value()` and `def _set_default_values(self)` have a name mismatch. Is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: @cezar, regardless of this, the result does not change.

Comment: Have you added the app containing `BaseModel` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`? Also, Django expects the `__init__` method to have the signature `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`